# How can I prevent twitter bootstrap from collapsing the top nav dropdown menus at browser widths less than 960px wide?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have tried playing with the various class min/max heights and widths in CSS and can't seem to prevent the top nav bar from collapsing my dropdown menus.  I would prefer a fixed width, but full screen menu fixed to the top.  The dropdowns work fine, but when I reduce the width of the browser window it collapses.  I've removed the toggle but no love from bootstrap. Here is the code from bootstrap 2.0:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="brand" href="./index.html">Brand Name&nbsp;</a>
        <ul class="nav">
           <form class="navbar-search">
             <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search Active Page...">
           </form>
        </ul>

       <ul class="nav pull-right">
               <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Pages<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">My Pages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">New Page</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Share Your Pages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page Browswer</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li> 

               <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="icon-cog icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Settings<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Upload Images</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Upload Files</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Other Accounts</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Manage Labels</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </li> 
           <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="img/small_fb_pic.jpg" vspace="5px"></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               John<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>      


        </ul>  <!-- end left justified menu items -->


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solved by commenting out the @media sections of bootstrap.css and specifying a minimum width of 960px.

Comment: you might want to post this as a reply to your own question and mark it as solved (it can be done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for responsive design on websites that can adjust to screen size (particularly on mobile devices). Learn more here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

To fix this on your bootstrap solution, go to the bootstrap customize page, uncheck Responsive Layouts and re-download your bootstrap files.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html

It's better than editing the bootstrap files manually, imo.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a terrible solution. Know the code! Learn bootstrap classes! Figure out how it works.

Answer (score 6):

The width definitions for the fluid layout are contained in `css/bootstrap-responsive.css` you can change the ranges at which bootstrap will collapse the menu by simply changing the `min-width` and `max-width` values in the `@media` definitions.

For example to make the navbar collapse in a window less than `800px` replace navbar related `@media` declarations containing `max-width: 980px`  with `max-width: 800px`. Do the same for `min-width`. At the time of writing, these changes happened to be on lines `105`, `281`, and `381` such that each line changed to look like the following (they are probably different now):

105: `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 800px) { ... }`

281: `@media (max-width: 800px) { ... }`

381: `@media (min-width: 800px) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

For 3 very useful solutions see this link:
http://taylor.fausak.me/2012/03/15/dropdown-menu-in-twitter-bootstraps-collapsed-navbar/

I ended up using option 1 on his list...  the basic gist is to edit your Responsive.less or Responsive.css if you don't have access to the .less source, as such:

Add: 
    :not([data-no-collapse="true"])

Everywhere the following class stylings are defined. 
    .navbar .dropdown-menu

(I found 7 places in the responsive.less file)

Then, where you define your html, you'll want to add an attribute as:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
        {{ account.FirstName}} {{ account.LastName }}&nbsp;
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-no-collapse="true">
        <li><a href="/logout.cshtml">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notice the data-no-collapse attribute on the unordered list.

EDIT:
Now your dropdown will not expand...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about Bootstrap version 2. Maybe someone looking for an answer for Bootstrap 3 will arrive here. This answer is for you!

1. Go to [Bootstrap customization page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
2. redefine the @grid-float-breakpoint value for something hardcoded (e.g. 520px) or for a smaller screen size like @screen-xs-min
3. Press the button at the bottom of the page to recompile the css files
4. substitute your bootstrap.css and bootstrap-min.css files with the ones from the downloaded zip file.

Comment: In Bootstrap v3.1.1 none of above mentioned tricks work. It ignores all "@screen-xs", "@screen-sm" and "@screen-xs-min". I tried. It shows on mobile emulation mode, bot on phone it shows navigator in collapsed state.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to bootstrap-responsive.css file
2. Go to line number 952
3. Change the width to the width at which you want the nav bar to collapse

Answer (score -2):

Remove the stylesheet link to bootstrap-responsive.css from your HTML and nothing will collapse anymore.

Comment: He wants to use bootstrap, just doesn't want navigation to collapse. Your idea is not a solution for this problem.